# Export content from a yammer network

Tags: export, backup, yammer

How can I export all threads - including attachment - from a yammer-network ?

Background

we have used the free version of yammer for a while - and it has now been decided to use a paid version. Because of that I need to backup all post/images/etc on our existing network.

But so far I have been unable to find a suitable tool to do this - and the export utility is not available for a free instance (which will be closed down eventually) ?

plaease advice - thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be hidden on the developer portal, however there is a [data export API](https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/admin-guide/monitoring-your-data/export-data/), which is available to paid networks. You will need to use API credentials from a verified admin account to execute the API. Normal user accounts are unable to execute the data export endpoint.